# Can I configure dhclient to execute a bash script after a successful DHCP renewal?

Tags: networking, server, bash, dhcp

I'm still new to Ubuntu, and just installed Ubuntu-server 14.04.3 LTS.  I've signed up for dynamic dns and opted to use a bash script by updating my ip address on the dynamic dns website's exposed REST API through a simple wget command.  I plan to just execute the bash script after a dhclient (DHCP) renewal, but I don't know how to configure dhclient to do such a thing.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

I've found a solution to my problem.  `man dhclient` states that a script is invoked by `dhclient` when it gets a lease.  Further reading of `man dhclient-script` and the actual script itself describes the location of scripts that `dhclient` executes depending on the phase of the dhcp process.

The hooks are located in `/etc/dhcp/dhclient-enter-hooks.d` and `/etc/dhcp/dhclient-exit-hooks.d` directories for before and after `dhclient` execution.  Since I'm interested in executing a script after a successful renewal, I placed my script inside the `...-enter-hooks.d` directory.

Here's the script, checking for the particular phases which signify a new dhcp ip address before executing the dynamic dns script:

```
case "$reason" in

    BOUND|RENEW|REBIND|REBOOT)
        sh /etc/network/rinker.sh
        ;;

esac
```

I got `rinker.sh` from http://www.changeip.com/accounts/downloads.php?action=displaycat&catid=4, which is just a simple wget call to the website's update URL.

Comment: As an alternative, if you are using debian, the `ddclient` can do the same as rinker, and the script came with the package.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to follow up to Poly Bug's answer.

When calling the external script I have found IF you use the 'sh' it 'source' before calling the script dhclient will treat that as "part of its hook".  As a result it will give you errors like this:
[[: not found
If you have if / then statements within the script you are calling it will end up in failure of the hook script you intended to run.

Instead, remove the sh and run your dhclient-exit-hook script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
# dhclient is picky about how it runs sub-scripts.
# using this way allows divorces it from the hook itself so it runs independently of the hook
/SM/data-drive/sm_scripts/network/dhclient-resolv-set $0 $BASH_SOURCE $reason &
```

This will run your called script in an asynchronous manner without errors.

I have also created a video follow up based on this post:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s4lU7IuUUto